# Recording maillog data for longer period of time?

Tags: redhat, email

I have recently had some problems sending emails from my server. 
When I looked at the maillog, it only goes back a day or two.

Is there anyway to either increase the size of the log or archive the old data for viewing at a later date?

This is on a Red Hat server.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, what's in `/var/log`?  If you're running a normal RH box, there will be `maillog.1` or `maillog.1.gz`, and some other similar files, which are made by logrotate.

If you can confirm those are there, we can talk about how to configure logrotate to do what you want.

Edit: OK, then you need to look in `/etc/logrotate.d` for some entries relating to maillog.  Are there any?  If so, could you post what seems relevant?

Comment: There is a single maillog file, however there are some similar ones in that format, such as messages.1 messages.2 etc

Comment: logrotate.d is an empty file

Comment: Do you have something scheduled in cron related to logrotate?

Comment: logrotate.d should be a directory.  Is it not?